# Как мне вернуться к моменту в цикле while?

Tags: python

Мне нужно вернуться в момент, когда я уже захожу на сайт и если неправильно что-то ввел, то вернуться в момент, где нужно ввести то, что не правильно, а не с самого начала (надеюсь поняли)

```
while True:
    a = input('Введите логин')

    if len(a) < 5:
        print('слишком мал')
    else:
        b = input('введите пароль')
        if len(b) < 5:
            print('слишком мал')
        else:
            print('вы вошли на сайт,пароль: {} и логин: {}'.format(a,b))

    c = input('Вы заходите на сайт,введите логин ')
    if c == a:
        v = input('введите пароль')
        if v == b:
            print('вы вошли на сайт')
            break
        elif v != b:
            print('пароль неверен')
    elif c != a:
        print('логин неверен')
```

Comment: Пропиши дополнительные условия или в функции запакуй и когда не верно, то начнется функция которая снова будет просить ввести верное

Answer (score 1):

Видимо вам нужно что-то подобное, добавить еще один while

```
while True:
    a = input('Введите логин: ')
    while len(a) < 5: # пока пользователь не введет логин больше 5 символов
        print('слишком мал: ')
        a = input('Введите логин: ')
    else:
        b = input('введите пароль: ')
        while len(b) < 5: # пока пользователь не введет пароль больше 5 символов
            print('слишком мал')
            b = input('введите пароль')
        else:
            print('вы вошли на сайт,пароль: {} и логин: {}'.format(a, b))

    while True: # пока пароль и логин не будут введены правильно 
        c = input('Вы заходите на сайт,введите логин: ')
        if c == a:
            v = input('введите пароль: ')
            if v == b:
                print('вы вошли на сайт')
                break
            elif v != b:
                print('пароль неверен: ')
        elif c != a:
            print('логин неверен: ')
    break
```